# List in Resource.XAML and access in ViewModel

Tags: list, xaml, viewmodel, application-resource

how to create a list in resources.xaml ( I will use it as itemsource for my listbox) and how can I access it in ViewModel? Thanks

Comment: The ViewModel getting stuff from the view does not sound very clean to me.

Comment: @JohanLarsson Yups I know it's kinda inappropriate, but according to my boss I should separate UI related stuff, that's why I will create a list in resources instead of ViewModel. I'm actually having a hard time to implement this. My real goal is to create three static items in a list i.e(name,age,gender) then when I click the item I should navigate to their respective page. Can you help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add the lists to app.config and create properties in the ViewModel that resolves the data from app.config. Then bind the view to those properties? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779117/how-to-get-a-liststring-collection-of-values-from-app-config-in-wpf) is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help : [Silverlight: Declaring a collection of data in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599066/silverlight-declaring-a-collection-of-data-in-xaml)

You can then access it by using the Resources property of the control you declare the collection in.

EDIT For example:

You need to declare a new collection type as you can't declare a generic type in XAML:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace YourNamepace
{
    public class Genders : List<string>
    {
    }
}
```

Then you declare a list in XAML, after adding the necessary namespaces:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Genders x:Key="AvailableGenders">
        <sys:String>Female</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Male</sys:String>
    </local:Genders>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can of course declare it with more complex data structures inside. Then, use that as your ListBox's ItemsSource:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AvailableGenders}}"/>
```

That works, I've tested it just now :-)

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know if the items from the list can be used as item source for my listbox? I mean the one created in XAML?

Comment: Sure, you can use something like `ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource YourCollectionKey}}`

Comment: I cannot create a list using XAML for some reason, would you mind to show me some example aside from the sample found at the link you have provided? Thanks much for you help.

Comment: Thanks much for the patience and answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @JerimyGilbert answer, you can populate the list from the class and use it directly from XAML like so:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace YourNamepace
{
    public class Genders : List<string>
    {
       public Genders()
       {
          Add("Male");
          Add("Female");
       }
    }
}

<Window.Resources>
    <local:Genders x:Key="Genders"/>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticReource Genders}}/>
```